# Error Trying to get property 'nombre' of non-object en laravel

Tags: php, laravel

Error:

> Trying to get property **'nombre'** of non-object

A la hora de recoger el registro nombre de la tabla Etiqueta mediante `foreach`.

**Código**

```
    $etiquetas =  $request->etiquetas; //Variable que recoge las IDS de un select2 que paso por AJax
    $ETIQUETAS = Etiqueta::all();//Variable que recoge todos los registros de la tabla Etiqueta
    $nombres = [] ; // Array vacio

    foreach($etiquetas as $etiqueta) // Primer bucle extraigo el primer registro del array del select2
    {
        foreach($ETIQUETAS as $ETIQUETA) //  Segundo bucle saco todos registro de la tabla Etiqueta y comparo su columna  ID  con el del seelect2, 
        {
            $ETIQUETA = $ETIQUETA->id;


            if($etiqueta == $ETIQUETA) //si la condición se da lo que hago es meter el Nombre de la etiqueta en el array $nombres, ya que lo que necesito mostrar es el nombre y no la id.
            {
                $nombres[]=$ETIQUETA->nombre;

            }

        }


    }

    Log::info($nombres);
```

Comment: Revisa pacientemente tu código. No entiendo por qué pones nombres de variable similares usando mayúscula/minúscula ¿? Luego, otro error: dentro del `foreach` has dicho que cada parte se llamará `$ETIQUETA`  y luego, en el cuerpo del bucle, a) haces una nueva asignación a esa misma variable; b) haces una comparación con `if` .... ¿? ¿? ¿? . Deberías implementar un código claro.

Comment: Edito y explico un poco el código

Comment: Una aclaracion si el código lo cambio a $nombre[]=$ETIQUETA; eso me devuelve un array perfecto pero con id por eso necesito pasarle el nombre "->nombre"

Comment: Quita `$ETIQUETA = $ETIQUETA->id;` y compruebalo en el if directamente: `if($etiqueta == $ETIQUETA->id) { $nombres[]=$ETIQUETA->nombre; }`

Comment: Ha funcioinado pero entonces por que esa declaracion me ha estropeado el array? Mushicimas gracias

Answer (score 0):

Claro, no te funcionaba porque al hacer $ETIQUETA = $ETIQUETA->id; rompías el arreglo de ese foreach.